# How do I find out what a blank icon in Windows 10 tray bar?

Tags: windows-10

I have a tray icon in Windows 10 that is blank and doesn't respond to left or right click. How can I find what's putting it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Settings > Personalization > Select which icons appear on the taskbar*.

You will see all the applications displayed with their icons,
so you can identify the one with the blank icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is software available where you can find out information about a window. I don't know the name of such software unfortunately, I just know that they exist. Usually they call it a windows spy or something like that.

Another way to find out is by killing all your processes one by one, and after you kill a process, hover that icon. The moment it vanishes upon a hover, then you know what program caused that icon.

Keep in mind, a process can be genereted by a service too, in which case, killing the program may restart the service.

You can also try hovering the icon and see if a tooltip window comes up that gives you any information about the process. If you have a hunch, kill that process first and see if you can remove the icon by hovering it.

Comment: To add to your answer, the task manager will typically display apps with no icon as not responding (in an ideal world)

Comment: @CaineKiewit the icon in the taskbar does not have to be the same as the app from the program, and by that definition, it possibly won't show as not responding in the task manager.